# Concatrelated with two parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to use Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function in a database for City Council Ordinances. I have one working properly, but this one in an unbound field should produce a string of councilor names of those who voted yes. It has two parameters and keeps returning a 3601 error, too few parameters. Votes are tallied as 'Y' or 'N'. I will need a sister string for 'N'

```
=ConcatRelated("[Lname]","[qryVoteTally2]","CO2_IDfk =" & [CO2_ID] & " AND " & "Vote = 'Y'")
```

The underlying SQL is

```
SELECT mmVotes.CO_ID2fk, mmVotes.Vote, tblSponsors.Lname
FROM mmVotes LEFT JOIN tblSponsors ON mmVotes.Counc_ID = tblSponsors.Spon_ID
```

The query works on its own. Why?

Comment: Notice *CO2_IDfk* in `ConcatRelated` vs. *CO_ID2fk* in the source query.

Comment: Thanks, the field should probably be named CO2_IDfk in the mmVotes Table but that doesn't affect the join

Comment: Has the problem been resolved then?  If not, what do you get with this version? `=ConcatRelated("[Lname]","[qryVoteTally2]","CO_ID2fk=" & [CO2_ID] & " AND " & "Vote = 'Y'")`